# Surgeon says white plaques found everywhere in abdomen, what is it?

Tags: cats

This is a continuation from [Cat is not eating, Fluid build up in abdomen, Ultrasound reveals mass in small intestine](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10024/cat-is-not-eating-fluid-build-up-in-abdomen-ultrasound-reveals-mass-in-small-i)

Basically, my cat went into surgery today to have the small intestine mass removed. He has not been eating/drinking and fluid has been building up in his abdomen.

When the surgeon went in, he did not find a mass...instead, he found a section of the intestine covered in white plaque and thickened. He also found white plaques in several other areas and all throughout the abdomen.

He also said the white plaques in the intestine was causing "diffusion" and fluid build up in the abdomen.

He doesn't have a definitive diagnostic of what it is.....but he thinks it could be either cancer or FIP (indoor cat only). He did take a white colored antibiotic 1 day ago.

He will be taking biopsies of the plaques and sending them to pathology which will take a week for diagnosis.

Does anyone know what this is? Is it cancer? Can we treat/cure it?

Comment: Glad you got some answers, but the mystery remains! Guess you'll have to wait for the lab results to come back. Unfortunately, the vet knows best, so we can't be of any further use, here. Only our vet can answer those questions, as they all depend on the lab findings.

Comment: The white antibiotic isn't related to this. Outside of that... If the vet, with far more info (including direct observation of the condition) isn't sure, there's no way we could answer. A more useful question might be how to care for a cat with FIP, if that is what it turns out to be. If it's cancer, the question will be exactly what kind, and whether the treatment prognosis will be good enough to justify making the cat uncomfortable while they undergo treatment. Quality of life trumps quantity.